# If I Rapidly Click the Browser Back Button Twice, The User is Logged Out in Our Cake App

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, browser-history

This is a weird bug, and I'm not even sure how to begin figuring out what's going on.

We are using Cake 1.3.8 with our sessions in the database.  I am not using ACL or any other access control.  If we navigate into the application and click around a bit, and then rapidly click the browser back button twice (I've tried in Firefox and Chrome) the user is logged out more often than not and receives the error message 'You are not authorized to access that location'.

All of my searches thus far have involved people wanting to make the page inaccessible if a user logged out and then used the back button.  I'm not seeing anything reported with regards to the issue I'm seeing.

Does anybody know if this is a Cake issue or have any thoughts on debugging what is going wrong?

Update: I found where the problem is.  I have the security set to high, because we need the session to be closed whenever somebody closes the browser.  I also have the timeout set very high because we do large binary uploads to S3, and don't want the user logged out while it's uploading or downloading.  The specific block of code in cake_sessions.php that's causing the problem is:

```
$time = $this->read('Config.time');
                $this->write('Config.time', $this->sessionTime);
                if (Configure::read('Security.level') === 'high') {
                    $check = $this->read('Config.timeout');

                    $check -= 1;
                    $this->write('Config.timeout', $check);

                    if (time() > ($time - (Security::inactiveMins() * Configure::read('Session.timeout')) + 2) || $check < 1) {

                        $this->renew();
                        $this->write('Config.timeout', 10);
                    }
                }
                $this->valid = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess this is because session IDs are regenerated between requests when security = high. Source:

http://book.cakephp.org/compare/44/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables/cakephp/cakephp1x

You only need one out of sync request, say for a missing image and you will lose the session. I've generally found it unworkable because it's not possible to prevent users double-clicking on links and buttons and invalidating their session.

I would think about using medium security, setting the session timeout fairly short and using an AJAX script to refresh the session at regular intervals (eg every 60s). That way the user will be logged out quickly if the tab/window is closed.

If security is a priority I would suggest hacking the core to make sure the session cookies are set to http_only to help guard against session hijacking by XSS attacks. Cakephp 1.x supports PHP4 so probably isn't setting this by default.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: I cheated, but this is indeed what the problem was.  I ended up changing my cake_sessions.php to give the behavior that I wanted - the session ending when the browser closes - to all levels of security.  Then, I set the security level to medium.  Back button no longer logs people out.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the session is erased and before it can be written again, the back button is clicked removing the auth from the session variables.

Page loads -> Back Button Clicks -> sessions is erased (but before session is rewritten) -> Back button clicks -> Session checks no existing session.

Comment: That's a brilliant thought.  Now, the question becomes, how can I prevent it?  I am going to go digging in the code and see if it deletes and inserts rather than updates.

Comment: Try adding the pr($this->Session) in the beforeFilter(). Navigate through a few pages then hit the back button really quick a few times. Check the page you go back to and see if the Session looks the same as it did prior.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think is happening is that when you're going back a page too quickly your code can't validate the person quickly enough (round trip from checking credentials) and throws an error that gets displayed on the next page that is loaded (second backed-to page).

Are you sure the person is actually logged out, or is it just the error being thrown?

Without seeing any code, it will be difficult to nail it down any further.

Comment: The person is definitely logged out.  If I move to another page, they are presented the login button.